# How to overlay a widget on an overlay widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Need help. Tell me, how can I implement such a widget, where the picture is superimposed on the picture with an overlap and the last circle is with a number about the number of remaining widgets (avatars)? As I understand it, this is used by Stack and a list of images is added to it?

Comment: Yes, using a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answer is `Stack` widget in combination with `Positioned` widget:
I have made demo to explain the implementation process, CustomWidget made to accept list of widget and convert them into stack.

[image: result]

And the code:

```
    class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> demoImages = [
    'https://www.nicesnippets.com/demo/following2.jpg',
    'https://www.nicesnippets.com/demo/following1.jpg',
    'https://www.nicesnippets.com/demo/following3.jpg',
    'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSgqRbJqrabB7q76uOOjEs2Oljk4CGBNpRdCNR4qhLnRWkIX0LKnLmedNS-ILmArB9cCaM&usqp=CAU'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: PhotoWidget(photosLinks: demoImages),
    );
  }
}

class PhotoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotoWidget({Key? key, required this.photosLinks}) : super(key: key);
  final List<String> photosLinks;

  List<Widget> getPhotos() {
    if (photosLinks.isEmpty) throw Exception('List is Empty');
    var tmp = <Widget>[];
    var maxNumber = (photosLinks.length <= 2) ? photosLinks.length : 2;

    if (photosLinks.length > 2) {
      tmp.add(Positioned(
        left: 2 * 40,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30,
          child: Text(
            '${photosLinks.length - 2}+',
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++) {
      tmp.add(Positioned(
        left: (40 * (1 - i)).toDouble(),
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(photosLinks[i]),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return tmp;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 150,
      child: Stack(
        children: getPhotos(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tell me, if I want to use a list with images, how can I do it?

Comment: And it is necessary that at the end there is an icon without a photo that writes the number of elements remaining in the list

Comment: The provided list is network images or local assets?

Comment: from the network

Comment: The data will come from the server. I just want to understand how it will be necessary to write everything in the code

Comment: I've refactored the code for you, try it and if it worked accept the answer and vote. any more question I'm happy to help

Comment: Yes, everything works. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the snippet

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 64,
  child: Stack(
    children: List.generate(
      itemCount > 3 ? 3 : itemCount,
      (index) => Positioned(
        left: itemCount == 1
                      ? null
                      : 32.0 * ((itemCount > 3 ? 3 : itemCount) - index),,
        child: index ==0 && itemCount > 3
            ? CircleAvatar(child: Text("+ ${itemCount - 2}"))
            : CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor:
                    index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.purple,
              ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=665251d1f3ba9c473d742d404d58069b)

Comment: Yes, everything works. Thanks a lot for your help!